# What's the best way to do URL recognition with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

*Situation:*

I got one input field and it needs to check if the input value is a regular string or a URL (link to a website).

What's the best way to check this?

Comment: [take your pick](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+check+valid+url)

Comment: Hmm yeah, can't really decide which one's best tho'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?
```

from
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2rj36

Sample usage

```
var reg  = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/;

alert(reg.test("hello"));
alert(reg.test("www.hello.com"));
alert(reg.test("http://hello.com"));
alert(reg.test("http://www.hello.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The "best way" s very subjective and depends on your situation.

A general fact is that its impassible to determine if its a url or a string. If you dont say that all strings with "http://" is urls.

A url can be:

```
http://www.e.com
www.e.com
e.com
/test/img.jpg
img.jpg
/test/
etc. etc. (you get the point)
```

**EDIT:** To detect the first 3 you can use

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var pattern = /(\.)(AC|AD|AE|AERO|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AN|AO|AQ|AR|ARPA|AS|ASIA|AT|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BIZ|BJ|BM|BN|BO|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CAT|CC|CD|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|CL|CM|CN|CO|COM|COOP|CR|CU|CV|CX|CY|CZ|DE|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EC|EDU|EE|EG|ER|ES|ET|EU|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|GA|GB|GD|GE|GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GOV|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|ID|IE|IL|IM|IN|INFO|INT|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|JOBS|JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MG|MH|MIL|MK|ML|MM|MN|MO|MOBI|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MUSEUM|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NAME|NC|NE|NET|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NU|NZ|OM|ORG|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|PRO|PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|ST|SU|SV|SY|SZ|TC|TD|TEL|TF|TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TN|TO|TP|TR|TRAVEL|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UK|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|XN|YE|YT|YU|ZA|ZM|ZW)(\/.*|:.*)?$/i;
    return pattern.test(s);
}
```

This will match on all top domains.

Comment: A link to a website. So it would be one of the first three options you've mentioned.